# How do AC/DC Adapters (Wall Wart) prevent AC Noise Coupling to DC?

Tags: emc

I am wondering if AC noise (EMI) gets coupled to the DC side of the AC/DC adapter, what are the design methods used to isolate AC noise getting coupled to DC output in an AC/DC adapter. What are the relevant AC/DC adapter (Wall Wart) specifications that can help identify the quality of AC/DC adapters?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524885/laptop-charger-leaks-ac-while-giving-dc-voltage-at-the-same-time-how/524888#524888) may help.